# Data Exchange between 2 Applications

Tags: c, vb.net, dde, data-exchange

I have two applications
the first one programmed using C
the second with VB.NET

i want to Execute the first one and keep status updated to the second

is there a way to do that ?

i can change the source code of any one of them

Comment: are you passing data between the two programs or is there a place where the data is stored like a database that they both can read from? Is one program calling the other program? Are they both running at the same time and sort of "talking" to each other?

Comment: There is no DataBase, Yep the second call the other, the two running at the same time

Comment: I've done this in VB using an interface. I don't know if you can do the same thing in C.

Comment: Please tell me how in VB !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in VB you need to implement an interface between the two programs so you can pass parameters between them.

- remember to import "system" and "system.reflection"

In program1 (the calling program) I set this up:

```
Dim oType As System.Type
Dim oAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly
Dim oObject As System.Object

oAssembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\VB.NET\report3.exe")
oType = oAssembly.GetType("report3.r1") ' this is [root_namespace.class name]
oObject = Activator.CreateInstance(oType)
oObject.SetParams("a", "b")
oObject.show()
```

This causes report3.exe to run and sends it the "a" and "b" parameters as values.

Then in program2 (report3.exe), I set it up like this:

```
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class r1

    Implements IPlugin

    Public person As String = ""
    Public address As String = ""


    Private Sub r1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.TopMost = True 'optional

        Dim b1 As New Label()
        With b1
            .Location = New Point(10, 10)
            .Width = 200
            .Height = 20
            .Parent = Me
            .BackColor = Color.Blue
            .ForeColor = Color.White
            .Text = person
        End With

        call_addr()
    End Sub


    Public Sub SetParams(c As String, d As String) Implements IPlugin.SetParams
        person = c
        address = d
    End Sub

    Private Sub call_addr()
        Dim b2 As New Label()
        With b2
            .Location = New Point(10, 50)
            .Width = 200
            .Height = 20
            .Parent = Me
            .BackColor = Color.Red
            .text = address
        End With
    End Sub

End Class


Public Interface IPlugin
    Sub SetParams(ByVal c As String, ByVal d As String)
End Interface
```

Answer (score 0):

I could see there being complications with using C and VB but here's a place to start
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx